# How do we solve this system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$a,b \in \Bbb R$ and $$\frac{a^5b-b^5a}{a-b}=30$$ and $$a^5+b^5 =  33$$

I get that $a^6-b^6=(a-b)63$ But I have no idea how to solve after that. Someone could help me?

Comment: You are missing something in the first equation...

Comment: Please type the question correctly .

Comment: $\dfrac{a^5b-b^5a}{a-b}$ $= ab\dfrac{a^4-b^4}{a-b}$ $= ab\dfrac{(a-b)(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3)}{a-b}$ $= ab(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3)$.  But you need to say $\dfrac{a^5b-b^5a}{a-b}=\text{some number}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy also $(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3)=(a+b)(a^2+b^2)$

Comment: Could you please tell us how you get $a^6-b^6=(a-b)63$

Comment: $$\frac{ab(a^4-b^4)}{a-b}=\frac{ab(a-b)a^3+a^2b+ab^2)}{a-b}= a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4=30$$ $$a^5+b^5=33 $$$$a^6-b^6= (a-b)(a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5)= (a-b)(30+33)= (a-b)63$$

Comment: The problem comes from the KöMaL magazine: http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=B4577&l=en It seems we have a cheater who asks illegal help for solving the contest problems of KöMaL.

Answer (score 4):

$$ a=2, b=1 $$
works. So does $$ a=1, b=2. $$

If you draw a graph of $x^5 + y^5 = C > 0$ you find that $x+y > 0.$  Thus, with $$ ab(a+b)(a^2 + b^2) = 30 $$ we find $ab > 0.$ Then, with $a^5 + b^5 = 33,$ we have both positive.

Writing $$  a = r \cos \theta, \; b = r \sin \theta $$ and pulling out $r^5,$
we get
$$  33 \cos \theta \sin \theta (\cos \theta + \sin \theta) = 30 (\cos^5 \theta + \sin^5 \theta).   $$
Taking second derivatives, the left hand side has negative second derivative on $0 < \theta < \pi / 2.$ On the same range, the right hand side has negative first derivative until $\theta = \pi / 4,$ after which it has positive first derivative.   As a result, there are at most two points of equality, and we have already found those.

Comment: And how can we prove that this is the only solution?

Comment: You have two equations in two unknowns, so we know there can only be a finite number of $a,b \in \Bbb R$. Eliminate one unknown between the two using [resultants](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5Ba%5E5+b+-+b%5E5+a+-+30%28a+-+b%29%2C+a%5E5+%2B+b%5E5+-+33%2C+b%5D%5D), and we find one other real solution as $a = (33/2)^{1/5}, b = (33/2)^{1/5}$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, if $a=b$ the equation with the $30$ in the original question comes out $4 a^5 = 30,$ or $a = b = (15/2)^{1/5},$ which disagrees with your $a = b = (33/2)^{1/5}.$

Comment: @WillJagy: I was in a rush to watch _The Hunger Games_ (hehe), and totally overlooked the fact that since $a-b$ is the denominator of the first eqn, then $a=b$ is a forbidden case.